# Auto close ul.parsley-error-list after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

Here is what I'm trying to do: I want to hide the Error list after say 5 seconds.

I tried the following, but nothing seems to be working.

```
setTimeout(function() {
jQuery("ul.parsley-error-list").fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000);
```

Also tried:

```
setTimeout(function() {
jQuery("ul.parsley-error-list").hide('blind', {}, 500)
}, 5000);
```

Could you please help fix or guide if it would be possible to auto close the error list automatically after a few secondS

Comment: can you do anything to the ul? eg: $('ul.parsley-error-list').css('background-color','red');

Answer (score 1):

Can you give it a try:

```
setInterval(function() {
jQuery("ul.parsley-error-list").fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);
```